# Test around amazon S3 upload fails only on Circle CI using WebMock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-sdk, circleci, webmock

I have tests around uploading an image to S3, wherever it's tested I stub the request made.

All the tests pass locally but on circle CI I get the following exception:

```
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:get, "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/").
  with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

This was because I didn't have the ENV vars set for the AWS_ID and AWS_SECRET on CI